# send php variables via ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, submit

According to jquery API this is the wat of sending value asigned to a name with ajax

```
.data( key, value )
```

Problem is my values are already in php variables. how can i send them using ajax?

this problem is relate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405486/execute-php-file-with-ajax?noredirect=1#comment37757075_24405486) i asked yesterday. Still couldn't find a way to send php variables to another php page when a button is clocked. sad that jQuery API Documentation doesn't have examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have two php....let say page.php and ajax.php. If you call ajax.php from ajax in page.php you must write variables from php to javascript with something like

```
var data1 = <?= $data1 ?>;
var data2 = <?= $data2 ?>;
```

and then add these variables to ajax call.

Best regards,
nele

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var ajax_value1 = $("#ajax_value1").val();

var ajax_value2 = $("#ajax_value2").val();

 $.ajax({

     type: "POST",

     url: 'sample.php?ajax_value1='+value1+'&value2='+ajax_value2,

     //Specify the datatype of response if necessary

     data: $("#your_form_id").serialize(),

     success: function(data){

     }

});

</script>


<!-- Set your ajax value in html input fields -->

<input type="text"  name="ajax_value1" id="ajax_value1" value="<?php echo $ajax_value1;?>" > 

<input type="text"  name="ajax_value2" id="ajax_value2" value="<?php echo $ajax_value2;?>" >
```