# I want to call a php function in javascript and passing two arrays as argument in it.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to call php function "insert_item()" in java script function "display()" .I tried a number of methods but could not do it.Display function is called when i click on submit button.IN insert_item() function i want to insert data in oracle data database using sql query.Can you people help me?
thanks.

Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<BODY>
<p id="demo"> </p>
    <TITLE> Add/Remove dynamic rows in HTML table </TITLE>
    <SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">      
            var a=["Naeem","Rehmat"];
            var b=[];`enter code here`
            var i=0;
            var c=1;
            function display() {
                for( var l=1;l<=i;l++)      //this loop fill the array a and b                  {  var x='task'+l;
                   var y=document.getElementById(x);
                   b[l]=y.value;
                   //alert(y.value);
                }
                for(var l=0;l<i;l++)
                { // document.write(a[l] +'  '+ b[l+1]+'<br>');
                }

    // here i want to call insert_item() function and want to pass a and b arrays as an argument; 
    //  here i want to call insert_item() function and want to pass a and b arrays as an argument;

     }

         function check(id)
         {          for (j=0;j<a.length;j++)
                    {
                       if(id==a[j])
                       { c=0;           }        }

        function addRow(tableID) {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex;
            var y = document.getElementById("mySelect").options; 

            check(y[x].text);
            if(c){          
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "checkbox";
            element1.name="chkbox[]";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = rowCount;

            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2); 
            cell3.innerHTML=y[x].text;      
            a[i]=y[x].text;
            i++;

            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);                      
            cell4.innerHTML='<input type="text"  ' + ' name='+ '\"' +'task'+i+ '\"' + '  id=' + '\"' + 'task' +i + '\"'+' />';  }
            c=1;   
     }

        function deleteRow(tableID) {
           try {
           var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
           var rowCount = table.rows.length;

           for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
               var row = table.rows[i];
               var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
               if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                   table.deleteRow(i);
                   rowCount--;
                   i--;               }
            }
            }catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
         }
     </SCRIPT>
<?php
   function insert_items($a,$b)
   {
      //echo "<br> Naeem <br>";
      //here i want to display a and b arrays data;  }
?> 
</BODY>
```

Comment: You say you've tried a number of methods but don't seem to include any of them. Perhaps include the most promising method and say what problem you encountered.

Comment: Once the page hits your browser, the PHP no longer exists.  The only way to call a PHP function is using Ajax -- that gives you a term to search on.

Comment: You would have to do this through ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24405486/execute-php-file-with-ajax

Comment: Javascript is client side, PHP is sever side. If you want to send something to the sever  and back, you will need to use ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP code runs on the server, while the Javascript runs on the client side. When the webpage arrives to the browser, the PHP no longer exists, and Javascript doesn't recognize it. You have to create another webpage (.php) which will hold the function and call this webpage from Javascript using Ajax. (this is called a backend page).
In your backen page (php only) - assuming it's called `insert.php`:

```
<?php
    function insert_items ($a, $b) {
        //Here you do your SQL database stuff
        //Make this value return what you want to print
    }

    echo insert_items($_GET["a"], $_GET["b"]);
?>
```

Now in your first page, you have to call the backend page (using an AJAX Http GET request - you can read more about ajax requests [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp))

```
var a=["Naeem","Rehmat"];
            var b=[];`enter code here`
            var i=0;
            var c=1;
            function display() {
                for( var l=1;l<=i;l++)      //this loop fill the array a and b                  {  var x='task'+l;
                   var y=document.getElementById(x);
                   b[l]=y.value;
                   //alert(y.value);
                }
                for(var l=0;l<i;l++)
                { // document.write(a[l] +'  '+ b[l+1]+'<br>');
                }

    // here i want to call insert_item() function and want to pass a and b arrays as an argument; 
    //  here i want to call insert_item() function and want to pass a and b arrays as an argument;
    $.ajax({ //Assuming you work with jQuery
        url: "/insert.php?a=" + a.join(',') + "&b=" + b.join(','),
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            //Here you can do anything you want with the data retrieved. data is the string returned from the webpage (the value that was returned from the function insert_items())
        }
    });

     }
```

> Note that in the PHP code, you won't retrieve the arrays as arrays,
>   but as strings with the , delimeter. You will have to split those
>   strings back into arrays in the PHP.

That way works Frontend-Backend communication usin ajax requests. If you don't use jQuery, you can see how to send an ajax request [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp)

Comment: Sure. Is there a reason for not accepting the answer as correct? Do you still need more assistance?